# JQuery/JS Regex "Invalid regular expression: missing /" Error

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, regex, django

I am designing a Django web app and having some trouble with a Regex error. The part that is not working correctly basically loads the details of any products in the database and displays them in a table. Next to the details, I want a button that will allow the user to view the product in greater detail. I haven't written that part of it yet but right now when I click on the button, it returns a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /` error. This is the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
  <h2 id="title">Create product</h2>
  <input id="name">Name</input>
  <br>
  <input id="description">Description</input>
  <br>
  <input id="price">Price</input>
  <br>
  <button id="add-product">ADD PRODUCT</button>
  </div>

  <table id = "product-table">
    <td>
      <button id = "myButton"></button>
    </td>
  </table>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    getData();
  });

  document.getElementById('add-product').onclick =  function(){
    sendData();
    getData();
  }

function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'product/view',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      $('#product-table').empty();
      var dmJSON = "http://localhost:8000/product/view";
      $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, f) {
          url = "product/view/" + f.id ;
          console.log(url);
          var button = "<button onclick=location.href"+url+"> View product </button>" ; 
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td> ID:   " + f.id + "</td>"  + "<td> Name:   " + f.name + "</td>" + "<td> Description:   " + f.description + "</td>" + "<td> Price   " + f.price + "</td>" + "</tr>";
          $(tblRow).appendTo("#product-table");
          $(button).appendTo("#product-table");  
          });
    })
  }})
}
```

The views.py file - not fully written:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from products.models import Product
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def viewProduct(request, idNumber):
    return HttpResponse('this is the {} user'.format(idNumber))
```

And lastly the urls file:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from products import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
    path('product/create', views.createProduct),
    path('product/view/<idNumber>/', views.viewProduct)
]
```

What I planned to do was when the data is loaded into the table to create a URL variable which would hold the product/view url and then use string concatenation to add on the id of the product to it. That bit works fine. My plan was then the urls.py would go the views file where I would implement the functionality to view the product in greater detail. Even now, if I go to the product/view/1 URL it returns the basic HttpResponse I have as a placeholder. However, when clicking on the button to go there, it does not do so and returns the error mentioned above in Chrome console. I am not sure what this means as I'm not using regular expressions or regex here to do anything so not sure how to solve.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: the url to the initial `$.ajax` call does not seem to match with what you have defined in the server.

Comment: You haven't posted enough information about the error to really know what's going on, but this line seems very suspect: `var button = "<button onclick=location.href"+url+"> View product </button>" ;` it doesn't come out to a valid HTML attribute at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is there a way to fix this? The href of the button needs to be set  using the id value from the Json data so not sure how else I would set it except without JavaScript and Jquery

Comment: Well as I say I don't even know if that's the problem. But you're obviously missing quotes around the value (`location....`) and you need `=` between `href` and the URL.